# With javascript, how do I wait for all .toBlob functions to complete before proceeding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, async-await

I'm processing images using javascript. For each image, I'm creating 4 files using .toBlob. The problem lies in the fact that .toBlob is asynchronous such that one .toBlob process can be running while the others have completed. await async does not seem to work. A counter for the number of images processed does not seem to work because the last image can be processed while a previous image has not finished. The last image increments the counter to the number of images and triggers a save.

I can do a setTimeout on the last image but that's just guessing at the max time.

Here's the code:

```
let kpData;
let repositoryData;
let collection;
let skuString = `,`;
let numImages;
let numImagesProcessed;
$(document).on(`click`, `.saveSkuImages`, function() {
    numImagesProcessed = 0;
    kpData = new FormData();
    repositoryData = new FormData();
    skuString = `,`;
    const skuContainer = $(this).closest(`.skuContainer`);
    const sku = skuContainer.attr(`sku`);
    numImages = skuContainer.find(`.skuImgContainer`).length;
    let i = 0;
    skuContainer.find(`.skuImgContainer`).each(function() {
        i++;
        sic = $(this);
        const skuImg = sic.find(`.skuImg`);
        const imgContainer = skuImg.find(`.imgContainer`);
        const img = imgContainer.find(`img:first`);
        cvs = $(`#${img.attr(`forcanvas`)}`);
        imgNum = parseInt(skuImg.attr(`imgnum`));
        const filename = `${sku}${imgNum > 1 ? `-alt${imgNum}` : ``}.jpg`;
        img.attr(`filename`, filename);
        if (cvs.length) { 
            createImages(cvs[0], imgNum, filename,i);
        } else { //if an image already exists, we didn't create a canvas for it and we don't need to recreate it.
            numImagesProcessed++;
        }
        if (sic.find(`.useForSeasonal`).is(`:checked`)) {
            kpData.append(`parentImage`, filename);
        }
    });
});

sgiArr = [`L`, `LI`, `I`, `K`, `Y`];

function createImages(loadedData,imgNum,filename,i) {
    const mime_type = `image/jpeg`;
    var cvs = document.createElement(`canvas`);
    //Create the detail version of the image
    cvs.width = 800;
    cvs.height = 800;
    ctx = cvs.getContext(`2d`);
    ctx.drawImage(loadedData, 0, 0, 800, 800);
    if (imgNum === 1 && sgiArr.indexOf(filename.split(`-`)[2]) >= 0) {
        // attach the size watermark to our primary image if it's a kid's product
        let watermark = document.getElementById(`sgi${filename.split(`-`)[2]}`);
        ctx.drawImage(watermark, 10, 720);
    }

    const newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type);
    const result_image_obj = new Image();
    result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
    if (imgNum === 1 && sgiArr.indexOf(filename.split(`-`)[2]) >= 0) {
        // display the image if we've attached the size watermark to it
        $(`img[filename="${filename}"]`).attr(`src`, result_image_obj.src);
    }
    cvs.toBlob((blob) => {
        let file = new File([blob], filename, { type: `image/jpeg` });
        kpData.append(`detail`, file, filename);
    }, `image/jpeg`,0.96);

    //create the general image
    cvs.width = 370;
    cvs.height = 370;
    cvs.getContext(`2d`).drawImage(loadedData, 0, 0, 370, 370);
    cvs.toDataURL(mime_type);
    cvs.toBlob((blob) => {
        let file = new File([blob], filename, { type: `image/jpeg` });
        kpData.append(`general`, file, filename);
    }, `image/jpeg`,0.96);

    //create the thumbnail
    cvs.width = 240;
    cvs.height = 240;
    cvs.getContext(`2d`).drawImage(loadedData, 0, 0, 240, 240);
    cvs.toDataURL(mime_type);
    cvs.toBlob((blob) => {
        let file = new File([blob], filename, { type: `image/jpeg` });
        kpData.append(`thumb`, file, filename);
    }, `image/jpeg`,0.96);

    //create the repository image for Amazon, Zulilly, Zappos and our wholesale customers. Zullily has the greatest minimum requirements so we'll use those for everyone
    loadedData.toBlob((blob) => {
        let file = new File([blob], filename, { type: `image/jpeg` });
        repositoryData.append(`imgfiles`, file, filename);
        numImagesProcessed++;
        console.log(`repository data created: `, numImagesProcessed, imgNum);
        if (numImagesProcessed === numImages) { // the process can get to here yet not all the previous .toBlob statments from previous images may have completed.
            console.log(`finished. Trigger save`);
            saveit();
        }
    }, `image/jpeg`, 0.92);
}
```

I've tried using an array of promises:

```
skuContainer.find(`.skuImgContainer`).each(function() {
    promises.push(processSku($(this),sku));
});
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    console.log(`promises are done:`,numFiles, numFilesCreated);
    saveit();
});
```

That made it even worse. The done function kicked off before the second iteration has even completed.
I tried incrementing a counter in each of the .toBlob functions but the counter didn't increment in time for a "if(counter===numFilesToCreate) saveIt();"

I'm at a loss.

Thanks

*UPDATE*  Here is the code I'm using for trying a Promise array:

```
$(document).on(`click`, `.saveSkuImages`, function() {
    numImagesProcessed = 0;
    numFilesCreated = 0;
    kpData = new FormData();
    repositoryData = new FormData();
    skuString = `,`;
    const skuContainer = $(this).closest(`.skuContainer`);
    const sku = skuContainer.attr(`sku`);
    numImages = skuContainer.find(`.skuImgContainer`).length;
    numFiles = numImages * 4;
    let i = 0;
    def = [];
    def = [];
    skuContainer.find(`.skuImgContainer`).each(function() {
        let skuFunc = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            processSku($(this), sku);
            resolve(``);
        });
        def.push(skuFunc);
    });
    ResolveAll();
 });
async function ResolveAll() {
    await Promise.all(def);
    console.log(`promises are done:`, numFiles, numFilesCreated);
    saveit();
}
function processSku(sic, sku) {
    console.log(sku);
    const skuImg = sic.find(`.skuImg`);
    const imgContainer = skuImg.find(`.imgContainer`);
    const img = imgContainer.find(`img:first`);
    cvs = $(`#${img.attr(`forcanvas`)}`);
    imgNum = parseInt(skuImg.attr(`imgnum`));
    const filename = `${sku}${imgNum > 1 ? `-alt${imgNum}` : ``}.jpg`;
    img.attr(`filename`, filename);
    if (sic.find(`.useForSeasonal`).is(`:checked`)) {
        kpData.append(`parentImage`, filename);
    }
    if (cvs.length) {
        console.log(`creating images`);
        createImages(cvs[0], imgNum, filename, i);
    } else { //if an image already exists, we didn't create a canvas for it and we don't need to recreate it.
        numImagesProcessed++;
        numFilesCreated += 4;
    }
```

*UPDATE 2*

The only reliable way to make this work is to check the fileCreatedCount against a fileExpected count -- in this case numFilesCreated vs numFiles -- in the .toBlob function:

```
function createImages(loadedData,imgNum,filename,i) {
    const mime_type = `image/jpeg`;
    var cvs = document.createElement(`canvas`);
    //Create the detail version of the image
    cvs.width = 800;
    cvs.height = 800;
    ctx = cvs.getContext(`2d`);
    ctx.drawImage(loadedData, 0, 0, 800, 800);
    if (imgNum === 1 && sgiArr.indexOf(filename.split(`-`)[2]) >= 0) {
        // attach the size watermark to our primary image if it's a kid's product
        let watermark = document.getElementById(`sgi${filename.split(`-`)[2]}`);
        ctx.drawImage(watermark, 10, 720);
    }

    const newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type);
    const result_image_obj = new Image();
    result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
    if (imgNum === 1 && sgiArr.indexOf(filename.split(`-`)[2]) >= 0) {
        // display the image if we've attached the size watermark to it
        $(`img[filename="${filename}"]`).attr(`src`, result_image_obj.src);
    }
    cvs.toBlob((blob) => {
        let file = new File([blob], filename, { type: `image/jpeg` });
        kpData.append(`detail`, file, filename);
        numFilesCreated++;
        console.log(numFilesCreated);
        if (numFilesCreated === numFiles) {
            console.log(`got the right number of files`);
            saveit();
        }
    }, `image/jpeg`, 0.96);
    //create the general image
    cvs.width = 370;
    cvs.height = 370;
    cvs.getContext(`2d`).drawImage(loadedData, 0, 0, 370, 370);
    cvs.toDataURL(mime_type);
    cvs.toBlob((blob) => {
        let file = new File([blob], filename, { type: `image/jpeg` });
        kpData.append(`general`, file, filename);
        numFilesCreated++;
        console.log(numFilesCreated);
        if (numFilesCreated === numFiles) {
            console.log(`got the right number of files`);
            saveit();
        }
    }, `image/jpeg`, 0.96);


    //create the thumbnail
    cvs.width = 240;
    cvs.height = 240;
    cvs.getContext(`2d`).drawImage(loadedData, 0, 0, 240, 240);
    cvs.toDataURL(mime_type);
    cvs.toBlob((blob) => {
        let file = new File([blob], filename, { type: `image/jpeg` });
        kpData.append(`thumb`, file, filename);
        numFilesCreated++;
        console.log(numFilesCreated);
        if (numFilesCreated === numFiles) {
            console.log(`got the right number of files`);
            saveit();
        }
    }, `image/jpeg`, 0.96);
    //create the repository image for Amazon, Zulilly, Zappos and our wholesale customers. Zullily has the greatest minimum requirements so we'll use those for everyone
    loadedData.toBlob((blob) => {
        let file = new File([blob], filename, { type: `image/jpeg` });
        repositoryData.append(`imgfiles`, file, filename);
        numImagesProcessed++;
        numFilesCreated++;
        console.log(numFilesCreated);
        console.log(`repository data created: `, numImagesProcessed, imgNum);
        if (numFilesCreated === numFiles) {
            console.log(`got the right number of files`);
            saveit();
        }
    }, `image/jpeg`, 0.92);
}
```

So, each of the four .toBlob functions in each iteration of createImages checks to see if it is the last file that needs to be created and if it is, it kicks off the save.

The problem was the createImages was reporting as having finished before all the files were created which then meant that creating a promise from that was meaningless. If .toBlob had a defer method or some way to .toBlob().then(), it would work.

Comment: Looks like you would want to use the [`all` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Tried that, too. Exact same result:  Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
  console.log(`promises are done:`, numFiles, numFilesCreated);
  saveit();
 });